# Select Data which have all comma separated strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

I have a table of conditions like

```
id   condition   member-id
 1    Fall         A1452
 2    Fall         A1453
 3    Dementia     A1452
 4    Dementia     A1453
 5    Fall         A1450
 6    Headaches    A1453
```

Now what I want is to pass conditions as parameter like **"Fall,Dementia"**
I want those member ids which have both **Fall** and **Dementia** condition

```
select * from conditions where condition IN('Fall,Dementia')
```

This return 3 records but I need those who have both?

remember "Fall,Dementia" are dynamic it may change to "Fall,Dementia,Headaches"

Comment: Look at this article http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
 select MemberId from 
 conditions
 where condition IN('Fall','Dementia')
 group by MemberId
 having count(distinct condition )=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select distinct MemberId 
 from StackOverflow4
 where Condition in ('Fall','Dementia')
 group by memberId
 having count(MemberId)=2
```